# How to create sqlite3 table columns from a list? (in python)

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to build a table columns according to a user request (the size of the list may change, that's why I can't determine an exact number of question marks):

```
userInput=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
ct.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chars(?)',(userInput))
```

I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Comment: what SQL query do you expect to get ? where do you have column names and columns types. I'm not sure but `?` expects only one element but you have many elements.

Comment: I don't query yet, tried to add types and it didn't help. The size of the list may change, that's why I can't determine an exact number of question marks.

Comment: maybe first generate one string with column names and column types and then use it as single argument in query.

Comment: Is there any smart way to do so besides creating a loop that concatenates the question marks string (?,?,?,?,?...) with the argument parts altogether?

Comment: you can create `"?,"*number` and then you have to remove last comma using `"?,?,?,"[:-1]`. Or you can concatenate list elements using join - `",".join(list_with_strings)`. If you have only column names in userInput then use  `",".join(userInput)`. But every column needs type so if `a`/`b`/etc.  keeps name and type then you need `",".join( "%s %s".format(x.name, x.type) for x in userInput )` or something similar.

Comment: You cannot pass structural components like column names as parameters only data values usually in `WHERE`, `ON`, `VALUES()`, and `IN()` clauses. You will need to concatenate list values to SQL string.

Comment: Also, never allow the user to structurally modify your database schema. Application/scripts should always be abstracted from databases with developer in full control. This can lead to a dangerous, runaway script!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, we will ignore security issues. I assume you want to create (untyped) columns according to your python list.

```
CREATE TABLE chars (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
```

Here is my proposal:

```
userInput=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
q = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chars(%s)" % ", ".join(userInput)
```

(Note that the column names must be quoted, per the Python syntax of string literals).

It may be argued that %s as a syntax is "de-emphasized", but in my humble opinion it is nicely terse in that case.